# unittest a function in python

Tags: python, dataframe, python-unittest

I have a function that gets the column count from a dataframe.

After the function is ran I want to ensure that the column count is the same as the input column count.

So, I have two variables inside the function, colinput and coloutput.

When I am running a unittest file in a new file, I am inporting the function (let's call it getweight()

so, from mainscript import getweight

Inside getweight I have the two column counts calculated

How can I write a test that compares colinput == coloutput?

I am getting stuck on the part of how to import those variables from the mainscript file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the relevant code instead of describing it!

Comment: You don't. Normally, a unittest would pass a dataframe into the function and then test its output (e.g., columns). Do it with the edge conditions that may cause a problem. You can't test all possible dataframes of course. If you have variables in the function to check, then do the check in the function, perhaps an assert.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the computation under test into a pure function. Make sure main is importable without side effects (use '__main__' guards):

main.py:

```py
import pandas as pd

def getweight(x: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  # ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # run your computations
```

Import main module and test properties you are interested in:

unittest.py:

```py
import pandas as pd
import main
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
  'x',
  [
    # specify interesting inputs ...
  ]
)
def test_getweight_preserves_column_count(x: pd.DataFrame):
  assert len(x.columns) == len(main.getweight(x).columns)
```

* not tested